What is someone to do if they inherited a laptop containing illegal images
I recently read something online about someone who claimed they were helping their father with handling the estate of his recently deceased uncle and discovered their uncle's laptop contained a large quantity of 'illegal images', from context I presume he meant child pornography.
The writer states they were uncertain what to do legally.  They were afraid deleting everything would possible constitute destroying evidence, and that it wouldn't really delete everything if he just did a normal delete.  However he was afraid that turning in the laptop to the police would get him arrested for possession of the images.
In the USA what would the legal responsibility be in such a situation, and how would one best protect themselves from the risk of an overzealous prosecutor attempting to pin them with a crime?
The thing I read didn't clarify what state the writer lived in, so I suppose pick any state you want for discussing state laws?

IANAL, but from what I understand, deleting evidence is usually only a crime if that evidence is needed for an investigation, or might reasonably be expected to be needed for an investigation. The presumption here is that the crime of possessing these images was committed by someone who is now deceased, and cannot be prosecuted for it, so it seems reasonable to expect the images would not be needed for an investigation.

Destroy it. Suppose later you put the laptop in for repair, and they find the deleted images? Were they yours? Get rid of it. When I scrap a computer, I physically destroy the hard drive with a hammer. Not because there is anything illegal, but some of its content is personal, and there is information about jobs for clients.

... or just replace the hard drive, which you should destroy, and then reinstall an OS.

@kaya3:  Production of the images is also a crime, and it would be reasonable to expect that having copies of the images would be helpful in investigating that crime.

@MichaelSeifert It's reasonable to expect that it would be helpful in an investigation, but the question is whether it's reasonable to expect that an investigation will take place. I would guess that in most cases, investigations don't look further than just prosecuting the person who possessed the images, but that might just be my cynicism.

@kaya3 Police might well be interested in any node that can help them roll up an entire network at once.

I think one can reject an inheritance?

@gerrit that would just put the father of the person in the original story in possession of the laptop and facing the same problems, as the executor of their Uncle's will Father needs to do something with it.  Plus it doesn't change the fact that the nephew had undeniable possession of the images at one time.

that it wouldn't really delete everything if he just did a normal delete - it depends what a "normal" delete is and what kind of drive this was. EDIT: not that they could have/should delete it, I am just commenting on the technical aspect.

Throw it into the Mariana Trench and never talk about it again.

Contact their lawyer
AFAIK all jurisdictions have an innocent possession defence, but if the optics don’t look good, a zealous police officer or prosecutor may bring charges, and they may be successful. Go straight to your lawyer, do not pass Go, do not collect $200; or you might end up going straight to jail.
First, your lawyer can give you advice or refer you to one who can. Second, your conversations with your lawyer are privileged, so they can’t be used in court unless they and you think it’s a good idea.
Don’t delete them - they are evidence of at least one crime, and even though the owner of the laptop is dead, other criminals aren’t. Tampering with evidence is a serious crime in itself.

This is just "good question, I don't know, a lawyer might". Which is kinda obvious on law.se. Why is this the highest voted answer?

it's the answer because sometimes the solution to your problem is that you need professional help to avoid getting in a lot of trouble

@DonQuiKong: this answer isn’t that a lawyer might know what to do, this answer is “take it to a lawyer”.  Whether the lawyer immediately knows what to do, or not is irrelevant.  It is not stated in this answer, but even if the lawyer is incompetent or actively hostile to the best interest of the executor and bungles whatever procedure should have been used, there is benefit in being able to say “this was a privileged client attorney communication”.

@DonQuiKong The answer here is "GET COUNSEL NOW - it protects your ass", which is as close as we can get to legal advice here.

I don't understand what the problem is with answering a hypothetical question with possible legal scenarios instead of saying "this shit's so deep, better don't even try to understand the legal implications." How are people supposed to become law-literate if the answer always is "sorry, it's better for you not to know just half so you don't accidentally think you know enough".

@DonQuiKong: again, this answer isn’t “this is deep shit get a lawyer”.  If the executor was a US Supreme Court justice, this answer would still be correct.  Unless the executor is a police detective, this is the right answer. And even then….

@DonQuiKong The issue here is not that a lawyer can give better advice, the issue is that there are simply things a lawyer can do you can't. This isn't fair, but life's not fair. There may be no way you can handle this situation on your own that doesn't risk you getting convicted unfairly of a crime, depending on various details of your local justice system. A lawyer can, for example, take possession of an object you can't legally possess, and show it to the police, without providing them with evidence that you ever possessed it. There's physically no way you can do that yourself.

Even if you received advice from a lawyer on this question, if that lawyer were for some reason not retained by you as legal counsel, their advice to you would be "immediately find and retain a lawyer as formal legal counsel".

@GlennWillen a lawyer who gives you legal advice is your lawyer and information shared is legally privileged. A lawyer doesn’t need to be paid or retained for this.

@GlennWillen that would be an answer because it actually contains a solution to the problem. This answer however fails to indicate how a lawyer would help.

What if you don't know something is "evidence"? One might think the images are disgusting and throw the laptop on a fire.

@AndrewMorton it doesn’t matter what you know. It matters what a reasonable person would know.

canada
There is an "innocent possession" defence where there is no blameworthy state of mind in coming into possession of the material, and where continued possession is solely for the purpose of delivering the material to authorities. See R. v. Chalk, 2007 ONCA 815 at paras. 24–25 (internal citations removed):

The "innocent possession" line of authorities was helpfully examined by Green J. Green J. points out that some of the "innocent possession" cases recognize a public duty defence as for example where an accused takes possession of contraband to deliver it to the authorities. In other cases, "innocent possession" is said to arise from the absence of an intention to exercise control beyond that needed to destroy the contraband or otherwise put it permanently beyond one's control. Green J. observes that in all of these cases there is, despite the existence of possession in the strict sense, an absence of a blameworthy state of mind or blameworthy conduct. Convictions for criminal possession by a technical application of the concepts of knowledge and control in these circumstances would overreach the purpose underlying the criminal prohibition against possession.
I agree with the analysis described above. There are cases where an individual has the requisite control and knowledge, but cannot be said to be in possession for the purpose of imposing criminal liability. These cases will include cases in which a person takes control of contraband exclusively for the purpose of immediately destroying the contraband or otherwise placing it permanently beyond that person's ability to exercise any control over the contraband. In such cases, the intention is solely to divest oneself of control rather than to possess. Like the other appellate courts whose discussions are referred to above, I do not think that criminal liability should attach to that kind of brief, "innocent" possession.


Contact a lawyer (the notary handling the inheritance might be able to act in that capacity or assist you) and probably the police as well (in case of CP this might automatically be the FBI in the US, not sure).
You identified CP in your possession, in many countries you're now in serious legal trouble (potentially) even if you weren't aware of the CP when you took possession of the device containing it (heck, even if you weren't aware it was CP you'd be in trouble in the EU, where you could in theory at least go to prison if someone sent you some CP in an anonymous text message, and then (using another anonymous phone) notified the police that you have it. Related but not identical: in the Netherlands (where prostitution is legal) customers went to prison when the prostitutes they visited turned out to have been minors, even after both they and the prostitutes testified under oath that ID cards showing the prostitutes to be adults had been provided, the IDs obviously having been fakes, child sexual abuse is taken that seriously here).
By handing it over as soon as possible to authorities you do the only thing an innocent recipient can do that makes them look innocent and cooperative. In the US, I'd contact the most senior law enforcement agency in your jurisdiction after contracting a lawyer, and with that lawyer go there and hand over the laptop and testimony as to how it came into your possession.

What you describe in the second paragraph is essentially framing and works without any technology (deliver anything illegal in someone's mailbox, then call the police that happens to stand around the corner "look, they have CP / drugs / weapons / ...").  Do you have a source that this would actually lead to a (successful) prosecution?

Why not let the lawyer handle the handover? Because of attorney-client privilege, the police cannot question your lawyer about your identity.

@MSalters I assume the police will want to question the owner (most recent) of the laptop as to where it came from, things like that. This is essential even if only to establish a chain of evidence

just because the police want something doesn't mean that you should want it

@jwenting: And that is exactly why you let the lawyer do the handover. Being questioned is a no-win situation.

What does CP stand for ?

@Stewart Child Porn.

@gerrit: well, if you go to the police to admit a strict liability offence of possession then you throw yourself on the mercy of the prosecutor. The defendant of course can claim not to know they had the contraband, but the prosecution has no burden to prove that they did know. One just has to hope that prosecutorial discretion will be applied in all cases where such defendants are telling the truth. It's an extraordinary bind, because if you don't go to the police then almost certainly you commit both the original strict-liability offence plus meet the mens rea of some more offences.

So, specifically in the US, engaging an attorney to negotiate immunity from the offence of possession of your uncle's laptop, in return for disclosure and testimony, might well be the safest play. I don't know. Ofc it's expensive and still not entirely risk-free. And I don't know because if there's no particular reason for the person in the question to look at their uncle's laptop (e.g. they're not  required as executor to check on it for financial records and so on), then "format the hard drive, and if asked lie and claim it was password protected" also sounds like it might be quite low risk.

... it's criminal, of course, especially if the person and the father are conspiring to lie. But with strict-liability offences of possession, the ship has sailed on not being criminal. It's one of the reasons they're so deeply unsettling: they put people in a position where the smart play might be to risk further crimes in order to cover their original, completely blameless crime that they had no means to avoid. Legislating such offences undermines the rule of law.
